# Pikachoose jquery slide show plugin not working in IE

Tags: jquery

I am using pikachoose a jquery plugin for picture slide show but its not working in IE 6,7.

[Here is the link](http://pwiser.com/pikame/pikachoose_test.html).

I want to use the `user_thumbs` option of Pikachoose, its working fine in FF but not in IE 6, 7. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try updating your Pikachoose version? I noticed you're using one from 4/1/2009. He has since updated it and the recent version is from 5/11/2010.  You can download it here. http://pikachoose.com/download version 3.2